# Mysterious current flow through socket

Tags: circuit-analysis, continuity

I was measuring a device that isn't working with an continuity meter. I've identified this socket as the problem.
[image]

It sits between the batteries and the rest of the device, I guess for loading the batteries. The positive red wire runs right through but the negative black one is soldered at two points (A and C in the picture). 
Now if I measure at point B, which is the negative contact of the socket, I get connection to both A and C. But if I measure between A an C directly, there is no connection. 
How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket is being used as a switch. Usually these contain a switch contact to allow disconnection of the battery power when the plug is inserted and reconnection when the power jack is removed. Figure 1 shows a typical example.

[image]

*Figure 1. A guitar stomp-box with battery and external power input. Note that this arrangement is using a switched positive. Yours may be using a switched negative. Source: [DIY Strat](http://diystrat.blogspot.ie/2009/06/how-to-wire-up-stomp-box-effects-pedal.html).*

If you have no contact between A and C when the jack is removed then it is likely that the socket is broken.

Comment: If I put in a plug, it's sleeve has connection to A (the batteries) but not to C (the device). I guess that makes sense, since the batteries should be loaded. By what you are saying, if I remove the plug there should be a connection between A and C. This is not the case, so I guess the switch in the socket is broken?

Comment: With that hint I got it. There is a contact pushed to the outside, disconnecting A and C when a plug is inserted. It doesn't retract enough when I remove the plug. The mystery was created because when I measured B and C, I unknowingly pushed B in a little :-)